# Rails + Docker - How use Heroku stack image but update the Ruby version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, heroku

While doing local Rails 6 development, via Docker, using the latest Heroku stack image as the starting point (`FROM heroku/heroku:20-build`), what does a Dockerfile need in order to replace the 'old' version of ruby in the stack image with a newer version from a Heroku ruby buildpack?

For Dockerized Rails development, starting with a Heroku stack image *seem* like the right way to maintain dev/prod parity to minimize those hard to debug "it worked locally then broke on Heroku" issues.

However, even the *latest* version of a Heroku stack image (20-build) does *not* include the current "default" version of ruby (2.7.3 at the moment)... even worse what it comes with is 2.7.0 and avoiding any ".0" version is generally wise.

Looking at the github pages for Heroku's buildpack (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby) I see no clues how the buildpack can be used to install a newer version of Ruby to a Dockerfile.

I know from an article I found online that Heroku has Ruby 2.7.3 available at https://heroku-buildpack-ruby.s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-18/ruby-2.7.3.tgz

However I cannot see how in the Dockerfile to replace the existing 2.7.0 with that version 2.7.3 without breaking everything.

On *older* Heroku stacks and buildpacks you could do something like this:

```
apt remove -y --purge ruby && curl -s --retry 3 -L https://heroku-buildpack-ruby.s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-18/ruby-2.7.3.tgz | tar -xz
```

but doing this with heroku/heroku:20-build does not successfully install the new version of ruby in the right path and it breaks rubygems so that a simple `gem list` throws an error (`undefined method` rubyforge_project=' for class `Gem::Specification' (NameError)`)

(I considered but dislike the idea of installing some ruby version manager like rbenv in the app's Dockerfile... the app only needs one version of ruby, and it introduces another pointless dependency, so hopefully there is a reasonable way to simply upgrade ruby in the image)

Comment: You have declared your ruby version in the gemfile?

Comment: Yes. Which AFAIK does nothing towards updating the ruby version in a docker container.